# Adding thumbnails independent of images in blog posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is it possible to add thumbnails to blog post listings independent of images in a blog post -- e.g. if there is no image in the blog post, can I add a thumbnail image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add thumbnails to blog post listings independent of
>   images in a blog post

set the 'featured image' when writing/editing your post; and use [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) within the loop, in the template.

> e.g. if there is no image in the blog post, can I add a thumbnail
>   image?

dependent on a post image, you can check (in your template, in the loop) if the post contains an image, and then output the post thumbnail, for instance with:

```
if( !strpos(' '.$post->post_content, '<img ') ) the_post_thumbnail();
```

details depend on your design.

Comment: Thanks.

I added images to the posts and I clicked 'Use as featured image'

But I didn't click 'Insert into Post'

It looks like it's doing the trick.

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you mentioned here, but it sounds like it's along the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has_post_thumbnail()` conditional tag to check if the post has a thumbnail, if thumbnail was found, display it by calling the `the_post_thumbnail()` template tag. If there's no thumbnail found, display custom image.

Example:

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
    the_post_thumbnail();
else 
    echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( "template_url" ) . '/images/no-thumbnail.png" />';
```

Comment: I don't have much background knowledge on this: Where do I upload the thumbnail to? And do I add that code into the CSS? Is there a particular place in the CSS where I should add the code? Also, I have a style.css in a folder called 'wordfruit' and another style.css in a folder called 'twentyeleven' -- I think 'twentyeleven' stops hiccups with upgrades of wordpress, or something like that -- which style.css do I add the code to? This is to resolve the situation at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/after-installing-a-video-thumbnail-plugin-how-do-i-make-thumbnails-appear-for-po